# Api for directions (open street maps, google maps, etc.)

Tags: python, maps, openstreetmap, google-maps

I'm looking for a solution to my problem that meets a few requirements. I want to be able to calculate a route time (e.g. Denver to L.A., getting the amount of time to travel in between) that includes multiple stops.

I've looked at Google Maps Directions API, which only allows [10 stops in the URL](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints), Mapquest Open Street Maps, which only allows [15,000 transactions a month](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/open/directions-api/), and some embedded options as well.

My question is what would be useful for either a React Native Application, or in a python program? I've seen options for the google maps javascript api, but I'm not sure how to use it with react native. The easiest solution was to use one of these with a url (e.g. fetch('url_with_stop_parameters_that_returns_json_data)), but I didn't know if there was something like that out there that didn't have a limit. If there is an embedded option that doesn't have a limit, I'm open to that as well. I'm trying to explore multiple options from people that know better than my google searches can deliver. :)

Comment: "` I've seen options for the google maps javascript api, but I'm not sure how to use it with react native`" Did you try a small example? It works with no problems for me.

Comment: Woah thanks for finding this. This project got put on the back burner but it's still something I need to figure out haha. I can't remember if I ever got it to work. I don't think I did. Do you have an example I could look at?

Comment: @Mawg I believe my main issue was having an API without a limit. Have you had issues with the Google API in that regard?